# Se bloqueó la carga de un módulo

Tags: javascript, html, github, github-pages

Tengo este error en consola al subir mi proyecto a github pages..
Se bloqueó la carga de un módulo de “https://limbervue.github.io/limbervue/gallery_vuejs/assets/index-c8cf5f60.js” debido a un tipo MIME no permitido (“text/html”).
este es mi archivo index, les agradezco sus soluciones

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="./vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--GOOGLE FONTS-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka+One&family=Play&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <title>Vite + Vue</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content1" id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./src/main.js"></script>
    <style>
      #app{
        max-width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```